# JSP Error al alojar codigo en un mismo archivo

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

tengo un problema con mi código y realmente no entiendo.
Para ponerlos en contexto:

```
    <%
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String correoElectronico = request.getParameter("correoElectronico");
        String mensaje = request.getParameter("mensaje");

        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.enviarCorreo(nombre, correoElectronico, mensaje);

        response.sendRedirect("Index.jsp");

        if (nombre == null || correoElectronico == null || mensaje == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Todos los campos deben estar llenos");
        }
    %>
```

Esto que he mostrado, es el codigo que manejo en mi archivo JSP, este se encarga de comunicarse con mi clase java que es para enviar correos, existe el formulario y todo esta en orden, el problema esta que solo me deja usarlo cuando esta parte del codigo se encuentra en otro archivo .jsp y no en el mismo donde esta tambien el formulario.
Quiero hacer que funcione en el mismo archivo, puesto que he hecho esto con otros dos más y funcionan a la perfeccion.

El error que me sale cuando intento hacer todo junto es este:
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/Mail_Sender.jsp] en línea [23]
20:             String mensaje = request.getParameter("mensaje");

21:

22:             Mail mail = new Mail();

23:             mail.enviarCorreo(nombre, correoElectronico, mensaje);**

Me confunde, el codigo esta mas que bien, pero quisiera evitar el tener exclusivamente esa parte del codigo en otro archivo, para optimizar espacio.

Answer (score 2):

Los archivos JSP se compilan a Servlets.

En tomcat hay una carpeta `/work` donde se generan archivos que terminan en `_jsp.java`. Ahi puedes ver lo que está generando tu JSP y frecuentemente puedes ver errores como por ejemplo definir la misma variable dos veces en tu JSP o en un archivo incluido por el JSP.

Esta es la estructura de Tomcat:

```
Tomcat
 |-- backup
 |-- bin
 |-- conf
 |-- lib
 |-- logs
 |-- temp
 |-- webapps
 `-- work
      `-- Catalina
           `-- localhost
                `-- projectname
                     `-- org
                          `-- apache
                               `-- jsp
                                    |-- Mail_Sender.class
                                    `-- Mail_Sender.java    <--- aquí
```